# Difference between <types> and <message> in WSDL

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

What is the difference between `<types>` and `<messages>` in WSDL. I know `types` is used for defining the data types that are to be used in the WSDL document and the message contains the data that is to be transmitted. But in my project, I have to develop a WSDL for ticket request and generating the response. For the request, I am supposed to send parameters like `firstName` , `lastName` ,`noOfTickets` , `date` etc. I don't know if I have to initialize all the elements and give their restrictions in the `types` tag or in the `message` tag. I need to create a request XSD and a response XSD for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to define the types in separate XSD´s therefore I only import the XSD´s in the `type` element.
Advantage is here that you can use the same XSD´s in further WSDL´s.
All restrictions are done in these XSD´s and `message` only defines the required elements for the SOAP-Operation.

When you prefer to define your types in the WSDL itself I would recommend to define your restrictions in the `type` definition.

Here is the definition from W3 for type and message:

1. [WSDL Types](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_types)
2. [WSDL Messages](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_messages)